# how to convert pandas dataframe to json to use in django template

Tags: python, json, django, pandas

I'm trying to create json from dataframe

```
response_data = [
        { "x_axis": 30,  "y_axis":  30, "radius": 20, "color": "green" },
        { "x_axis": 70,  "y_axis":  70, "radius": 20, "color": "green" },
        { "x_axis": 110, "y_axis": 100, "radius": 20, "color": "blue" }
    ]
    result = HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type = 'application/json')
```

If I use above I would get

```
Content-Type: application/json [{"color": "green", "y_axis": 30, "x_axis": 30, "radius": 20}, {"color": "green", "y_axis": 70, "x_axis": 70, "radius": 20}, {"color": "blue", "y_axis": 100, "x_axis": 110, "radius": 20}]
```

which is exactly format that I want , but if I try to do it from dataframe using something like :

```
d = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.]),'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.])}
df0_fa = pd.DataFrame(d)
df0_js = df0_fa.to_json()
result2 = HttpResponse(json.dumps(df0_js), content_type = 'application/json')
```

I got this json format :

```
Content-Type: application/json "{\"one\":{\"0\":1.0,\"1\":2.0,\"2\":3.0,\"3\":null},\"two\":{\"0\":1.0,\"1\":2.0,\"2\":3.0,\"3\":4.0}}"
```

But I what I really want is

```
Content-Type: application/json [{"one" : 1.0,"two" :1.0},{"one" : 2.0,"two" :2.0},{"one" : 3.0,"two" :3.0},{"one" : null,"two" :4.0}]
```

what's  backslash do in here ?  and []  I have tried different orient setting but doesn't work. any recommendation would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're double converting it to JSON. `df0_fa.to_json()` is doing it, then `json.dumps()` is doing it. Just do: `result2 = HttpResponse(df0_js, content_type = 'application/json')`

Some notes on `to_json()`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

A good page on `json.dumps()`: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/parsingjson/

Comment: `HttpResponse(df0_js, content_type = 'application/json')` is not working for my case