# Pandas dataframe to json for django

Tags: python, json, django, pandas

I want to load some initial data into my django app for a model, but it needs this specific format:

```
[
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Lennon"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "Paul",
      "last_name": "McCartney"
    }
  }
]
```

All the other ways I tried put square brackets or index values that I don't want. In the dataframe, the index will map to "pk" and the column values should be those in "field" ("first name" and "last name" would be the target columns of my dataframe).

Using this code was the closest I got, but it adds square brackets around the values in "fields"

```
df.groupby(['model', 'pk'], as_index=False)
    .apply(lambda x: {"first_name": df.first_name[x['pk']], "last_name": df.last_name[x['pk']]})
    .reset_index().rename(columns={0:'fields'})
    .to_json(orient='records')
```

Comment: This may help : [how to convert pandas dataframe to json to use in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744384/how-to-convert-pandas-dataframe-to-json-to-use-in-django-template)

Comment: @Lemayzeur, that really only shares keywords with my question, it doesn't really address my problem

Comment: Share the structure of your pandas dataframe